# Prevent Obj-C code from passing `nil` to a Swift method with non-optional parameters

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm dealing with an issue where Obj-C code can pass `nil` to Swift methods that do not take Optional parameters.

I'm looking for a way for Xcode compiler to prevent this. It seems that all nullability annotations are for Swift to call Objc, not vice-versa.

Some example code:

```swift
// file1.swift
@objc
class Foo: NSObject {
  @objc let date: Date? // default to nil
  ...
}

// file2.swift
extension Date {
  @objc(doSomethingWithOtherDate:)
  func doSomething(with otherDate: Date) {
    print(date)
  }
}
```

Then in Obj-c, we call the Swift method passing in an optional value, with `nil`:

```objectivec
// file3.m
[Date.new doSomethingWithOtherDate:[Foo.new date]];
```

Is there a way to prevent this? How can we tell the compiler `doSomethingWithOtherDate` does not take `nil`.

#### Follow up

Following up on this issue, passing a literal `nil` on the call triggers a warning, which is very helpful. However, passing a `nil` value does not trigger anything. The static analyzer does however find the issue if the nil reference is local.

However, if a `nil` reference is passed via another object, the static analyzer fails to identify this issue.

[image: Objc - Swift crash]

I've made this repo to showcase this issue: https://github.com/eneko/ObjcCrashDemo

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. Objective-C does not have enough understanding of nullability to detect every case.

If you *explicitly* pass nil you should get a warning "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument". You can turn this into an error by adding `-Werror=nonnull` to "Other Warning Flags" in your build settings.

However this is extremely limited. Even something as simple as `NSDate* date = nil;` and passing that will produce no warning/error. Even adding a `nonnull` property in Objective-C and passing that will not produce a warning/error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've tried adding the flag, but as you mention, it didn't help in this case. This is a bummer. It seems, if there is no way to prevent this behavior, that the safest route is to make all Swift method tagged with `@objc` have only optional parameters. Far from ideal :/

Comment: yep, it is a bummer! bad news

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this article: https://fabiancanas.com/blog/2020/1/9/swift-undefined-behavior.html (search for the "Detecting nil when nil isn’t possible" section).  This article discusses a rather complex solution to the problem, but I would suggest the easier solution would be to declare your function argument type as `Date!` (either a value or nil) and then perform a `guard let` on the passed value before proceeding in the function body:

```
// file2.swift
extension Date {
  @objc(doSomethingWithOtherDate:)
  func doSomething(with otherDate: Date!) {
    guard let od = otherDate else {
      // do something else
      return
    }
    print(date)
  }
}
```

Comment: The danger of this approach is that you'll lose the benefit of Swift's type checker when calling this code from Swift, potentially turning compile-time errors into runtime errors when you accidentally pass a nil

Comment: Yep. For this, is much better to set the parameter to optional: `Date?` which will be safe both for Obj-C and Swift. Does not solve the question posted, though, which is about non-optional parameters.

Comment: The problem is inherent compatibility between Swift -> ObjC.  Going the other way (calling ObjC functions in Swift), it is possible to annotate ObjC function params as nonnull, which correctly declares the param types as non-optional in Swift.  Per the article, there isn't a way to address this scenario without some sort of a hack work around.  So your choice is either use the work around in the article or to work around by declaring the swift param type as ! or ?.